# Applications with 3d accelerated guis?

Tags: gui, opengl

Basically all games have this, since a game just creates a window and draws to it with opengl. The gui runs at the same fps as the game, usually 60 fps or more.

I'm wondering if gui libraries like gtk and qt have the ability to use 3d acceleration for widgets? I would imagine this working the same way as a game. Or if not gtk or qt, another toolkit?

Comment: As I remember, a long time back Gnome started requiring a graphics card with 3D capabilities. I think Qt does so also. Some of the "light" windows managers might not use such capabilities.